# Convert a Map<String, String[]> to a MultiValueMap<String, String>

Tags: java, collections

I have the following;

```
Map<String, String[]> params = getSrcMap();
```

and I need to convert to a  MultiValueMap<String, String> . I attempted:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String[]>(params);
```

which cannot be resolved as written (does not compile). Grateful for ideas. Thanks

Comment: Did you put the corresponding import ? Can you  show the error ?

Comment: Which library is this?

Comment: Spring UX sometimes really sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy, and with code that doesn't even require Java 8 Streams:

```java
MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : params.entrySet())
    multiValueMap.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks I adapted this to:
```
MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.forEach((key, value) -> multiValueMap.put(key, Collections.singletonList(value)));
```

Answer (score 3):

The [copy constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html#LinkedMultiValueMap-java.util.Map-) expects the value type to be a list, not an array. You'll need to convert your map first. Here's one approach with streams:

```
Map<String, List<String>> params = getSrcMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue())));
```

Or if you have a library like Guava you can transform the map with a function:

```
Map<String, List<String>> params = Maps.transformValues(getSrcMap(), Arrays::asList);
```

Or just create an empty map and populate it by hand:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
getSrcMap().forEach((key, values) -> {
    for (String value : values) {
        multiValueMap.put(key, value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `Map<String, String[]>` to `Map<String, List<String>>` so it can be directly passed to the constructor of `LinkedMultiValueMap`.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(
       params.entrySet().stream().collect(
          Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue()))));
```